# How to get value of an environment variable in Spark class?

Tags: apache-spark

we execute spark jobs on a cluster like so:

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=blah
spark-submit --class "com.myapp.MyClass" --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster ....
```

but when we try to access `HADOOP_USER_NAME` in `MyClass.scala` using [System.getenv](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()) we get a null value. Perhaps this is because the env variable does not get propagated to the machines running on the cluster. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Spark trick to set the `--conf` property with `spark.*` prefix and access it as any other properties using `SparkConf` or `spark.conf` configuration interface.

```
spark-submit --conf spark.HADOOP_USER_NAME=$HADOOP_USER_NAME ...
```

Comment: this is pretty much what we are doing. instead of adding it in conf we add to the command line options input to our JAR like -owner $HADOOP_USER_NAME

Comment: I think that there is no built-in mechanism for it in Spark.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv`. See: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html